# Цветовые схемы в less/sass. Миф или реальность?

Tags: вёрстка, sass, frontend, less

Развлекаюсь мини-проектом ради самообразования. И возник такой вопрос: кто-нибудь реально пишет свои цветовые схемы для сайтов в less или sass (или других препроцессорах), используя функции цвета? Если ли смысл заморачиваться?
В каких случаях это было полезно?

Какие инструменты и ресурсы вы использовали для написания зависимостей, составления цветовых схем?

Если поделитесь своими примерами, буду признательна отдельно. Заранее благодарю за любой ответ по теме.